# Separable partial differential equation with IVP

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, initial-value-problems

Determine all product solutions for $\frac{\partial u^2 }{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial u^2 }{\partial y^2}$.

Decide one solution that satisfies $\left\{\begin{matrix}
f(0)=0\\f(1)=0 
\\f(0.25)=0.5 
\\g(0.25)=g(0.50)=1 
\end{matrix}\right.$

I shall also determine the separation constant that meets the conditions.

I've done:
$$u(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)\\
\frac{\partial u^2 }{\partial x^2}=X''Y,\ \frac{\partial u^2 }{\partial y^2}=Y''X, \frac{X''}{X}=\frac{Y''}{Y}=-k\ (constant)\\$$

If $k=0$: $u(x,y)=(c_1x+c_2)(c_3y+c_4)$

If $k<0, k=-a^2$: $u(x,y)=(c_1e^{ax}+c_2e^{-ax})(c_3e^{ay}+c_4e^{-ay})$

If $k>0, k=a^2$: $u(x,y)=(c_1cos(ax)+c_2sin(ax))(c_3cos(ay)+c_4sin(ay))$

From $u(x,y)=(c_1x+c_2)(c_3y+c_4)$, I get $f(x)=(c_1x+c_2)$ and $g(y)=(c_3y+c_4)$.

$$f(0)=0\Rightarrow 0=c_2\\
f(1)=0\Rightarrow c_1=-c_2\\
f(0.25)=0.5\Rightarrow c_1=2-4c_2\\
-c_2=2-4c_2\Rightarrow c_2=\frac{2}{3}\Rightarrow c_1=-\frac{2}{3}\\
c_2=0\Rightarrow c_1=0\Rightarrow 0=2-4\cdot 0\Rightarrow 2=0$$

But that doesn't add up. I'm obviously missing something and making mistakes. What is it?

EDIT: Updated some spelling errors.

EDIT 2:
From $u(x,y)=(c_1e^{ax}+c_2e^{-ax})(c_3e^{ay}+c_4e^{-ay})$, I get $f(x)=c_1e^{ax}+c_2e^{-ax}$ and $g(y)=c_3e^{ay}+c_4e^{-ay}$.

$$f(0)=0 \Rightarrow 0=c_1+c_2 \Rightarrow c_1=-c_2\\
f(1)=0 \Rightarrow 0=c_1e^a-c_1e^{-a} \Rightarrow 0=e^a-e^{-a} \Rightarrow 0=a+a \Rightarrow a=0\\
f(0.25)=0.5 \Rightarrow 0.5=c_1-c_1 \Rightarrow 0.5= 0$$

From $u(x,y)=(c_1cos(ax)+c_2sin(ax))(c_3cos(ay)+c_4sin(ay))$, I get $f(x)=c_1cos(ax)+c_2sin(ax)$ and $g(y)=c_3cos(ay)+c_4sin(ay)$.

$$f(0)=0 \Rightarrow 0=c_1\\
f(1)=0 \Rightarrow 0=c_2sin(a) \Rightarrow 0=a\\
f(0.25)=0.5 \Rightarrow 0.5=c_2sin(0) \Rightarrow 0.5=0$$

I'm ending up with $2=0$, $0.5=0$ and $0.5=0$. What am I missing?

EDIT 3:
From $u(x,y)=(c_1cos(ax)+c_2sin(ax))(c_3cos(ay)+c_4sin(ay))$, I get $f(x)=c_1cos(ax)+c_2sin(ax)$ and $g(y)=c_3cos(ay)+c_4sin(ay)$.

$$f(0)=0 \Rightarrow 0=c_1\\
f(1)=0 \Rightarrow 0=c_2sin(a) \Rightarrow a=2\pi n \\
f(\frac{1}{4})=\frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}=c_2sin(\frac{2\pi}{4}) \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}=c_2\\
g(\frac{1}{4})=1 \Rightarrow 1=c_3cos(\frac{2\pi }{4})+c_4sin(\frac{2\pi }{4})\Rightarrow 1=c_4\\
g(\frac{1}{2})=1 \Rightarrow 1=c_3cos(\frac{2\pi }{2})+c_4sin(\frac{2\pi }{2})\Rightarrow -1=c_3\\
 \\
u(x,y)=(c_1cos(ax)+c_2sin(ax))(c_3cos(ay)+c_4sin(ay))\\ \Rightarrow u(x,y)=(\frac{1}{2}sin(2\pi x))(-cos(2\pi y+sin(2\pi y)))$$

Separation constant:
$$a=2\pi \\
k=a^2 \\
k=(2\pi)^2=4\pi^2$$

Comment: If $f(0) = 0 \implies c_{2} = 0$ then $f(x) = c_{1} x + c_{2} = c_{1} x$. Now applying $f(1) = c_{1} \cdot 1 = 0 \implies c_{1} = 0$. Hence, the solution with $k = 0$ doesn't satisfy $f(0.25) = 0.5$ condition and so the $k = 0$ case is out. Now do the other cases.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried the other two, but as you can see i couldn't figure it out. I feel lost and appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: Your mistake in the case $k < 0$ is that, while $f(0) = 0 \implies c_{1} = 0$ is true, $f(1) = 0 \implies c_{2} \sin(a) = 0$ means you could have **either** $c_{2} = 0$ (which would yield a solution that matches non of your conditions), **or** you could have $\sin(a) = 0$. What are the value(s) of $a$ that make $\sin(a) = 0$? Hint: draw a graph of $\sin(x)$ for $x \in [-4 \pi, 4 \pi]$ say.